# Why in flutter passing list as widget children won't update UI, but list.map() updates upon adding new child

Tags: flutter

I'm flutter novice and I have been struggling with problem of not updating children widgets on UI. With some attempts I have found that passing `list` as children of widget won't work after adding new element to `list`. But using `list.map((widget) {return widget;}).toList();` will work perfectly and the UI will be updating after adding new child

Simple examples:

Working:

```
class _SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {

  List<Widget> _buttons = new List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        children: _buttons.map((widget) {
          return widget;
        }).toList());
  }
  
  void _addChild(){
    setState(() {
      _buttons.add(new SomeWidgetChild(key: UniqueKey()));
    });
  }

  //some code...
}
```

Not working:

```
class _SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {

  List<Widget> _buttons = new List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        children: _buttons
    );
  }
  
  void _addChild(){
    setState(() {
      _buttons.add(new SomeWidgetChild(key: UniqueKey()));
    });
  }

  //some code...
}
```

I wanted to ask why simple passing list doesn't work in this case?

Comment: Check your second code well. There should be a loop in your _buttons. Better still separate that operation in a function

Comment: see [GridView.count](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c969b8af7b/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart#L1644) sources, it passes `children` to `SliverChildListDelegate` and this delegate overrides `shouldRebuild` method here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c969b8af7b/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/sliver.dart#L698 - place a breakpoint here and check how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are just missing just _buttons.toList();

```
return GridView.count(
   crossAxisCount: 4, 
   children: _buttons.toList() /// this is the thing you are missing....
);
```

see the full code running at this DartPad  [ListOfWidgetBuild](https://dartpad.dev/c1859638765b1ef4ebea4a5514695469)

feel free to comment for any error....

Comment: @Filip,....did this help to clear your concept in List of Widget....Please see the DartPad code and play with it

Comment: Yes, now I understand why GridView behaves that way. But I think it's quite odd to need using methods like toList() on list itself only just to create clone of this list

Comment: if it solved your concept, please accept the answer and also make upvote for my answer....

Answer (score 0):

As I understood with [pskink comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087477/why-in-flutter-passing-list-as-widget-children-wont-update-ui-but-list-map-u?noredirect=1#comment111561374_63087477), GridView is rebuild only when list of children is not the same as before. So passing reference to *_buttons* won't work because I passing all the time the same reference to list with only different contents.

Answer (score -1):

The first code is returning widget to the children property whiles the second code is not. Your second code should return widget to update the UI with.

Comment: Both returning list of widgets. When I initialize some widget in list, the second (wrong) example shows this initialized widgets, but it doesn't add new one when _addChild() method is called